# How to include CDATA tag on all XML nodes even when element is empty?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

Currently I'm using the code below to apply CDATA tags to elements.  The problem I'm having is that I need the CDATA tag to be applied regardless if there is data in the element or not. For instance - `<Column1></Column1>` would not have a CDATA tag and `<Column2>2</Column2>` would. How can apply to all elements? Thanks.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" 
                cdata-section-elements
                  ="Column1 Column2 "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Do you mean that currently `<Column1></Column1>` is not currently serialized with a CDATA marked section and you want it to be?  If so, perhaps it would help readers if you explain why it matters to you.   Do you have non-XML-aware software later in your tool chain?  Or ... ?

Comment: "*`cdata-section-elements` specifies a list of the names of elements whose **text node children** should be output using CDATA sections*" http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#output If your element has no text nodes, then there will be no CDATA sections.

Comment: For some reason the API I'm posting to requires all nodes to be present and the CDATA tag must be included even if the element has not text nodes.

Comment: The reason is the crass ignorance of the people who designed it. If you can, educate them - you will be doing the world a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space() or *)]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

By forcing the presence of a text node as a child of any element that has neither children or text, it'll get a CDATA added when it's output.

If you're using a library that doesn't allow this, you can potentially replace the `<xsl:text/>` with:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[]]></xsl:text>
```

although that's not guaranteed to work either, and personally I'd feel the need to go take a shower after writing XSL that uses DOE.

However, Michael's right, NO API should require the presence of an empty CDATA tag, it's definitely worth addressing this with whoever designed the API.

Comment: Yes I agree it is ridiculous, but unfortunately I don't have much say in the matter.  Thank you for the solution.

Comment: I have tested this with libxslt, [Xalan](http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38ZA) and [Saxon](http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38ZA/1) and it doesn't work with any of them.

Comment: I used .NET's XslCompiledTransform, which probably applies to msxml as well. I guess it depends how they choose to serialize the output; I'm honestly not sure how a text node of zero length SHOULD be handled. I tried xsltransform.net on firefox, and it didn't work there either.